# Как при помощи созданной кнопки отключать и включать музыку сразу во всем iOS приложении ?

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Здравствуйте. Я начинающий iOS разработчик, делаю свое первое приложение в Xcode 5 (простенькую игру) для iphone. Ситуация такая: есть основной (начальный) экран игры (View). При появлении этого экрана начинает играть музыка. На этом экране я сделал кнопку. Хочу, чтобы с помощью нее можно было бы отключать и заново включать музыку во всей игре (игра имеет несколько View). Ну, т.е.: "ткнул" на кнопку один раз - музыка выключилась, "ткнул" на нее же еще один раз - и музыка заново включилась, и так далее. Как реализовать это в текущем View я разобрался, но стоит только перейти на другой View (с новым классом, т.е. с новой парой файлов .h и .m) и там опять начинает играть музыка, принадлежащая этому новому окну, т.к. в этих новых файлах написан новый код, позволяющий проигрывать уже другую мелодию. И так далее: в новых View имеется новые мелодии... Как "заставить" все эти мелодии одной кнопкой "замолкнуть", или же "играть"? Не делать же на каждом новом View новую кнопку включения/отключения звука! Заранее спасибо за ответ! Надеюсь, что он будет не очень "замудреным", а то голова "кипит" от этого Objective-C! :-)))

Answer (score 2):

Если ты используешь отдельный класс для звука типа SoundManager, то добавь туда булевскую переменную, которая будет отвечать за состояние "вкл\выкл" и во время нажатия на кнопку меняй состояние этой переменной, а в других вьюхах следи, если "вкл", то проигрывать звук, иначе - нет.
Если у тебя нет отдельного класса для звука, то создай такую переменную в классе с кнопкой, а потом следи за ее состоянием в других классах.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но что-то никак не могу реализовать эту идею пока что...  маловато пока что моих знаний :(((  Пробую пока решить мою проблему хотя бы через switch...

Comment: скажи, что не понятно, что подсказать?
лучше использовать отдельный синглтон для звука, и там реализовать все плееры и методы к ним, и там же смотреть на "вкл/выкл". 
посмотри, например, сюда https://github.com/drhelius/iOS-SoundManager
если у тебя только один звук, то можно просто в MainViewController.h(это там, где кнопка) добавить @property (nontomic) BOOL isOnSound; в других классах ты смотришь на состояние этой переменной перед тем как включать звук. Собственно в синглтоне тоже нужна такая переменная :)